# Random selection by 2 layer strata in r

Tags: r, random, dplyr, sample

I have a large data set that I want to modify to look 'similar' to another dataset in proportions.

So target data set has proportions for variable X like this

```
'A' = 0.5,
'B'= 0.2,
'C'= 0.1
'D'= 0.2
```

And I want a group variable to be 2:1 ratio so that the data is for every trt there are 2 ctrl

My data looks like this:

```
 ID          GRP         X         Y
 1           ctrl         A        2
 2           ctrl         A        2
 3           ctrl         B        1
 4           trt          A        4
```

etc

I can make it into equal groups of X and GRP with this code:

```
DF%>% group_by(X, GRP) %>%sample_n(2500)
```

But I would like to get a 2:1 ratio for GRP and preserve that initial ratio of X. Is there a way to specify the percentage of the total group by strata in random sampling?

Comment: From the online doc:  "sample_n() and sample_frac() have been superseded in favour of slice_sample(). While they will not be deprecated in the near future, retirement means that we will only perform critical bug fixes, so we recommend moving to the newer alternative."

Comment: and "weight_by - Sampling weights. This must evaluate to a vector of non-negative numbers the same length as the input. Weights are automatically standardised to sum to 1."  I think that will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? (I used `replace = TRUE` because of the small dataset)

```
library(dplyr)
DF%>% 
  group_by(X, GRP) %>%
  mutate(prob = case_when(X == "A" ~ 0.5,
                          X == "B" ~ 0.2,
                          X == "C" ~ 0.1,
                          X == "D" ~ 0.2),
         prob = if_else(GRP == "ctrl", prob * 2, prob)) %>% 
  distinct(X, GRP, Y, .keep_all =  TRUE) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  slice_sample(n = 10000, replace = TRUE, weight_by = prob) %>% 
  count(GRP, X) 

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  GRP   X         n
  <chr> <chr> <int>
1 ctrl  A      5203
2 ctrl  B      2102
3 trt   A      2695
```